# Mutually Reference-able Instances in Python

Tags: python, design-patterns

Say I have a pair of instances that reference one another mutually. Is there a preferable manner to structure this relationship than the following.

```
class Human():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.pet = Dog('Sparky', self)

    def pet(self, animal):
        self.pet.receive_petting()


class Dog(Pet):
    def __init__(self, name, owner):
        self.name = name
        self.owner = owner

    def receive_petting(self):
        pass

    def bark_at(self, person):
        "do something"
```

The thing I don't like is that the relationship needs to be specified in two places. Any ideas on how to make this dryer?

Comment: There's nothing really Python-specific in this;  it's just a limitation of constructor based dependency injection.  You could use a "promise" and fill in the attribute at first dereference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would break this into three classes:

```
class Human():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class Dog(Pet):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def bark_at(self, person):
        "do something"

class OwnerPetRelation():
    def __init__(self, dog, human):
        self.owner=human
        self.pet=dog
```

Now, one owner can also have many dogs, we just need to define as many `OwnerPetRelation`s.

Similarly, a dog can also belong to multiple owners now.

Comment: But finding a human's dogs or a dog's humans now only works via traversing over all `OwnerPetRelation`s - which thus must be kept somewhere...

Comment: Exactly, this is the solution I initially leaned towards but this approach makes accessing the Human instance from inside a pet instance (or vice versa)  a bit more complicated. If the human instance was self I'd no longer be able to just write self.pet

Comment: seems like that would be easily solved by adding the relationship object to the owner and to the pet. Just add the attribute dynamically.

Comment: self.pet could just be a property descriptor that looks at the relationship objects and returns the ones that are pets.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a method on `Human` that allows you to add pets (since a human might have many pets):

```
class Human():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.pets = []

    def add_pet(self, pet):
        pet.owner = self
        self.pets.append(pet)

    def pet(self, animal):
        for pet in self.pets:
            pet.receive_petting()


class Dog(Pet):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.owner = None

    def receive_petting(self):
        pass

    def bark_at(self, person):
        "do something"
```

This can be used as follows

```
human = Human('Jim')
human.add_pet(Dog('Woof'))
```

This approach can of course also be used for just a single pet and one could also extend it to allow pets to be owned by many humans.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing really Python-specific here;  this is just a limitation of constructor-based dependency injection.  It's hard to inject a reference to another object that cannot have been created yet.  Instead, you can create an object that has a reference to something that *will* have a reference to the other object.  For instance, you can pass a function to the constructor that will be able to return the value:

```
class Human():
    def __init__(self,name,dog):
        self.name = name
        self._dog = dog

    @property
    def dog(self):
        return self._dog()


class Dog():
    def __init__(self,name,human):
        self.name = name
        self._human = human

    @property
    def human(self):
        return self._human()
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
human = None
dog = Dog('fido',lambda: human)
human = Human('john',lambda: dog)

print(dog.human.name)
print(human.dog.name)
```

```
john
fido
```

It is not hard to update this so that the property function caches the value, of course. E.g.:

```
class Dog():
    def __init__(self,name,human):
        self.name = name
        self._human = human

    @property
    def human(self):
        try:
            return self._human_
        except AttributeError:
            self._human_ = self._human()
            return self._human_
```